# Drupal 8 form value not changing with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, drupal

I have a drupal form, which contains a title, username, email, ... and I want the user to be able to insert some values and submit the data.
My problem now is that when submitting the form my values are unchanged.
Currently I am loading the data in with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("response").value = JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
```

The weird thing is that I see the value being changed but not when submitted.
This is how my form field currently looks like:
[drupal form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtNqM.png)

When submit is pressed the passed value will remain response_placeholder
Anybody that can help me?

Comment: show code not Image ? i think you dont have id in frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: remove the #disable: true line